# Is it appropriate to change the title of a question to reflect the definitive answer?

Tags: discussion, title

People have problems with paths in Python (and arcpy) when they're starting out.  There's the r'...' method, the double backslash method, and the forward slash method.  Occasionally you'll see problems pop up either as the root of the problem, or a piece of the problem in a question.

[SImple model works, resulting script doesn't](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29397/simple-model-works-resulting-script-doesnt):

> Edit: The question has evolved, but in a case where it hadn't I think this question is still valid.

Based on the title, people would be unlikely to find this answer through regular search mechanisms.

**Obviously in this case the asker wasn't asking 'How do I create paths to data in Python', but that's what the answer reflects.** Changing the title lend itself to an answer wouldn't prevent others from answering too because there's only one answer really.

If it's clearly the *only* problem with the script in a given question then it can be the defacto answer you link to from now on when you see a common problem.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say if there is a canonical answer then go for it (and link to it) but I wouldn't do it for every other question. Sometimes people searching for an answer don't know what the underlying problem really is in the first place so renaming questions based on the eventual answer might be counter-productive (and potentially a lot of work).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a good idea to me — on an occasional basis and not too long after the topic has subsided, so there is no needless noise in the "active" feed.